# How to add custom symbols to Regular Expression? DevExpress Mask

Tags: c#, regex, devexpress

I have following regular expression

```
(\w)+(,(\w)+)*
```

which is comma separated characters and numbers only

```
test123,test3,test9
```

I want to also add symbols like @, #, $ that can be used within \w

when i try [(\w)$@]   not worked.
I need to use it in DevExpress TextEdit Mask. it says syntax error

http://prntscr.com/pbyq7p

Comment: Look at the information page for the 'regex' tag, there is lots of helpful detail there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reply at the bottom if [this page](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T525499/regex-validation-is-not-working-in-the-textedit-control) which mentions that special characters cannot be used within `[]`.

The available character are listed on [Mask Type: Extended Regular Expressions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1501/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Simple-Editors/Editors-Features/Input-Mask/Mask-Type-Extended-Regular-Expressions)

The advice is to use grouping with an alternation to separate the character class and the special character.

You might try

```
(\w+|[@#$]+)+(,(\w+|[@#$]+))+
```

In parts

- `(` Group 1

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `[@#$]+` Match 1+ times any of the lister
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `(` Group 2

  - `,` Match literally
  - `(\w+|[@#$]+)` Same pattern as group 1
- `)+` Close group and repeat the whole group starting with `,` 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FaLynN/1)

If your data only consists of characters a-z and numbers only, you could also try

```
([a-z0-9@#$]+)+(,([a-z0-9@#$]+))+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O4ELqM/1)